# Firebase Firestore Chat messaging based on a topic

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a Vehicle Sell and Buy app, most of the pasts are done, listing and posting ads. What is the best way to structure a data model in Firebase Firestore to implement a chat messaging with seller and buyer based on a Listing (Vehicle) and set security rules to view only their contents.

The seller will be the message document owner, the buyer will be the document creator. All the tutorials show chat as group messaging. If you guys know any YouTube content showing what I am asking please share the links.

I am seeking help here because I want to finish this app in a week as I lost my abroad job due to the covid crisis.